# Connection Timeout after several successful requests jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, connection-timeout

I am new to jQuery.ajax, and I don't know what's wrong with my code. As the title states, I'm having problems accessing the site I created after several successful requests. Can't seem to find the the solution here. I hope someone can help me.

Here's my JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
async();
fetch();    
});

function fetch(){
setTimeout(function(){
    fetch();
    async();
}, 5000);
}

function async(){   
$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: 'message.php',
    data: '',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data){
        $('ul').children().remove();
        $.each(data, function(index, item){
            $('#lstip').append('<li>'+item.ip+'</li>');
            $('#lstmsg').append('<li>'+item.message+'</li>');
            $('#lstlike').append('<li><a href="message.php?like='+item.line+'">'+item.like+'</a></li>');
        });

    },
    error: function(xhr, stats, err){
        console.log(stats);
    }

}); 
}
```

Additional Info: 
 - It happens on every browser that I have (IE, Firefox, Chrome).
 - The site was uploaded on 000webhost.
 - There're no problems retrieving the data.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds like you should look at the network tab in the browser to see what's going on and then perhaps look on your server to see why connections are not getting through.

Comment: How long does `message.php` take to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  async().then(fetch);  
});

function fetch(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    async().then(fetch);
  }, 5000);
}

function async(){   
 return $.ajax({   
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'message.php',
    data: '',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    timeout: 5014,
    success: function(data){
        $('ul').children().remove();
        $.each(data, function(index, item){
            $('#lstip').append('<li>'+item.ip+'</li>');
            $('#lstmsg').append('<li>'+item.message+'</li>');
            $('#lstlike').append('<li><a href="message.php?like='+item.line+'">'
              +item.like+'</a></li>');
        });

    },
    error: function(xhr, stats, err){
        console.log(stats);
    }

}); 
}
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  async().then(fetch);  
});

function fetch(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    async().then(fetch);
  }, 5000);
}

function async(){   
 return $.ajax({

    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/23e61e522a14d45a35e1',
    data: '',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    timeout: 5014,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data.files["a.json"].content));
       // $('ul').children().remove();
       // $.each(data, function(index, item){
       //     $('#lstip').append('<li>'+item.ip+'</li>');
       //     $('#lstmsg').append('<li>'+item.message+'</li>');
       //     $('#lstlike').append('<li><a href="message.php?like='+item.line+'">'
       //       +item.like+'</a></li>');
       // });

    },
    error: function(xhr, stats, err){
        console.log(stats);
    }

}); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: will try this later. I just have some questions. Will it still be ok, if I set the timeout at 1000? Why was the timeout set to 5014 on ajax? and what is 'then' for? Thanks. :)

Comment: @Japoy To call `fetch` when promise object resturned by `async` resolved ; to call `fetch` if promise objected rejected try adding `.then(fetch, fetch)` ; see http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't work. got an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

Comment: @Japoy Which line returned `error` ? Can create stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: Sorry, i think it's now ok. Will just wait for a few minutes. And by the way, will it still work if I set the timeout at 1000ms? and is it really necessary to add 14ms at timeout on ajax? Thanks

Comment: @Japoy Yes, should return same results adjusting to 1000. No, additional 14ms not necessary; was attempting to consider 13 milliseconds at at `$.fx.interval` not applicable here.

Comment: can't upvote with my current reputation, but you've just resolved my question sir. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can try **setInterval()**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
fetch();    
});

function fetch(){
setInterval(function(){
    async();
}, 5000);
}
```

Comment: The error went away, but still getting a "timeout" error every 1000ms.